# indexing varchars without duplicating the data

Tags: mysql, database

I've huge data-set of (~1 billion) records in the following format

```
|KEY(varchar(300),UNIQE,PK)|DATA1(int)|DATA2(bool)|DATA4(varchar(10)|
```

Currently the data is stored in MySAM MYSQL table, but the problem is that the key data (10G out of 12G table size) is stored twice - once in the table and once as index.  (the data is append only there won't ever be UPDATE query on the table)

There are two major actions that run against the data-set :

1. contains - Simple check if a key is found
2. count - Aggregation (mostly)  functions according to the data fields

Is there a way to store the key data only once?

One idea I had is to drop the DB all together and simply create 2-5 char folder structure. 
this why the data assigned to the key "thesimon_wrote_this" would be stored in the fs as

```
~/data/the/sim/on_/wro/te_/thi/s.data
```

This way the data set will function much as btree and the "contains" and data retrieval functions will run in almost O(1) (with the obvious HDD limitations).

This makes the backups pretty easy (backing up only files with A attribute) but the aggregating functions became almost useless as I need to grep 1 billion of files every time. The allocation unit size is irrelevant as I can adjust the file structure so that only 5% of the disk space is taken without use.

I'm pretty sure that there is another - much more elegant way to do that, I can't Google it out :).

Comment: Sounds like you need a clustered index or index organised table and from a quick Google these don't exist in myisam

Comment: @MartinSmith - You gave me the right direction - I'll migrate the table to InnoBD one and see how much disk space it will take and check the query efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem like a very good idea to consider having a *fixed-width*, *integral* key, like a 64-bit integer. Storing *and* searching a varchar key is very slow by comparison! You can still add an additional index on the `KEY` column for fast lookup, but it shouldn't be your primary key.

Comment: There is no point of using int keys as the table won't ever be updated (or sorted) and the only time the "key" will be in use is for "Contains" checks and they will always contain the "key" name. Plus - it won't solve the double data saving